# Can I play with my friends on PS4 while I'm on PS Vita?

Tags: ps4, ps-vita

I'm on the PS Vita and my friends are on PS4, can I play games with them?

Comment: Depends on the game. I believe the relevant feature is called "Cross Play", but only very few games support it.

Comment: @Alex "Fixed question" suggested edit comment made me laugh :)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek oh... I just made a lot of grammar fixes and stuff so I put that

Comment: @Alex Don't take it personally, it's just a laugh :)

Answer (score 3):

You can but only with games supporting Cross Play.